# Blender 2.7 - Atalho para rodar game engine

Tags: blender

Abro o Blender 2.7 e tenho um cubo. Seleciono o cubo e, usando os botões de lógica, dou ações à esse cubo de acordo com as teclas que eu pressionar no teclado. Mas agora como faço pra rodar a game engine aqui na versão 2.7 e ver o jogo em ação? 
Nas versões mais antigas, bastava eu pressionar a tecla 'p', mas aqui na versão 2.7 eu pressiono 'p' e simplesmente não acontece nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O atalho continua na tecla P.

Certifique-se de que está selecionado em "Blender Game". Veja o screenshot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É da versão 2.69, mas segue o mesmo visual

Além disso, o cursor (mouse) deve estar no "Blender 3D View Editor".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era isso! Faltava eu setar a opção "Blender Game". Não me lembro de precisar disso nas outras versões. Obrigado!